# Как привязать exception из сервлета к jsp?

Tags: java, исключения, jsp, servlet

Пишу страничку логина по гайду

Вот doPost из сервлета:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    Login login = new Login();
    login.setUsername(username);
    login.setPassword(password);

    try {
        if (loginDao.validate(login)) {
            response.sendRedirect("admin_main.jsp");
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid login or password");
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Вот Error.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" isErrorPage="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Error</h1>
        <h2><%=exception.getMessage() %><br/> </h2>
    </center>   
</body>
</html>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при `throw new RuntimeException("Invalid login or password");` в Error.jsp  вызывался getMessage() у этого исключения или у любого другого. Другими словами, как привязать exception из сервлета к exception в jsp, чтобы в браузере выводился getMessage (в зависимости от того, какое исключение было брошено).

Comment: пихайте его в Response как тело, и статус ему такой же, типо 404. Не помню как точно делается, но примерно как `return Response.body("My own error").status(Response.PAGE_ERROR).build();`

Comment: ну и не бросайте его